# How can I access the value of a XML element using Xdocument

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to edit a record inside a XML document, using C#, with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Questionnaire>
  <Record>
    <Pile>1</Pile>
    <Serno>1</Serno>
  </Record>
</Questionnaire>
```

I'm selecting the record successfully by using:

```
SernoID=txt_Serno.Text;
XElement xml = XElement.Load("path");
XElement x = xml.Elements().Where(p => p.Element("Serno").Value.Equals(sernoID.ToString())).First();
```

Now, if the user changes any data in the winform, I want to update it into the xml file, for which I'm using:

```
x.Element("Pile").Value = txt_pile.Text;
x.Save("path");
```

However, it keeps only the modified record, and removes all the other existing records. It probably has something to do with the save command?

Can anyone help please?

Thanks!!

Comment: Don't save `x`, save `xml`?

Comment: x.Save(path); works for me in a single unit test? Could it be how the xml object is persisted between the load and update??

Comment: Save the `XDocument`, not the node.

Comment: Consider XmlDocument and query the document via XPath by using selectSingleNode, or SelectNodes.  XDocument (compared to XmlDocument) is pretty limited in my experience.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth i think you have them backwards.  `XDocument` is far, far more powerful than `XmlDocument` ever was, and fully supports XPath.

Comment: @Amy - Thanks, took a look around based on your comment, XDocument does look pretty good too.  Most of my code was written pre .NET 3.5 / LINQ so I guess I'm out of date...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is the result of your query, so it is a single `Record` element. You then save that to your file at the specified path. This has the effect of overwriting your file with just this single element.

Make your changes as before, but change this line:

```
x.Save("path");
```

To this:

```
xml.Save("path");
```

This will save the whole *document*, not just a single element.